# Adding the value of cells separated by 6 columns

Tags: excel

Is there a way to add the value of columns which are separated by a predetermined number of columns without having to do a: `=sum("cellA","cellB","cellC")?

Any advice is very welcomed - thank you.

Comment: Try using `OFFSET` ([reference](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/offset.html))

Answer (score 0):

This would require you to know the number of columns you want to add. In this example there are 5 columns (1, 7, 13, 19, 25):

```
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(A1:Z1,SEQUENCE(1,5,1,6)))
```

`SEQUENCE` lets you define how many columns, which column to start with, and how many to skip

`CHOOSECOLS` will use only the columns defined by `SEQUENCE`

`SUM` will add the values of those columns